# After processing form, How can I return to the Index.php?

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to make a message board with php, but when a new message is posted the page goes to add.php instead of staying at index.php.

I stores the messages from user in a text file.  When there is a new message, I append the file.  There are 4 file in my `www` directory - index.php, show.php, add.php and comments.txt.

My index.php looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>messages</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Messages</h1>
<div id="comments">
<?php include("show.php"); ?>
<?php include("add.php"); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My add.php looks like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['cmt'])) {
 $cmt = $_POST['cmt'];
 $fh = fopen("comments.txt", 'a');
 fwrite($fh, "B_E_G_I_N\n");
 fwrite($fh, "$cmt\n");
 fwrite($fh, "E_N_D\n");
 fclose($fh);
}
?>
<form action="add.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="cmt">
<input type="submit" value="ok"/>
</form>
```

I know my implementation is really bad, but I really want to make it work first.

Thanks!

Comment: At the end of your `if` block, just do `header('Location: /index.php');` followed by `exit();` - easy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add

`header('Location:index.php');`

at the end of `add.php`.

Also it goes to `add.php` because the form action says so

Answer (score 1):

After main script processing (i.e. `fclose($fh);`) place redirect to 'index.php' like `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`